# How does Angular 2 know the parent instance without any explicit code?

Tags: angular

Could anyone shed some light on me please. I have followed [this example](https://gist.github.com/nickjohnson-dev/bec769ee72fa2e8510323dce784cfab9) to sketch out a simple wizard app in Angular 2. It works like a charm, except - what actually bothers me is the constructor in file `my-wizard-step.ts`. How come the private property `private parent: MyWizard` becomes automatically populated and this line `this.step = this.parent.addStep();` in `my-wizard-step.ts` works out of the box?

I think there is something implicit going on which I don't quite figure out.

How does Angular know that the parent is an instance of MyWizard that contains MyWizardStep? It's almost, kind of equivalent of jQuery's `.closest('.myWizard')` but I don't know the Angular2's rules that stand behind it.

Anyone care to explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 2, every component has its own injector. These 'injectors' form a tree that mirrors the tree of the components themselves. This means that when you ask for a service in a component, the Angular DI system tries to find a provider for that service first in the injector of that component, and then in the injector for the parent component and continues upward throughout the component tree.

The last piece of the puzzle is that every component registers itself in its own injector. Therefore, in your example, when you ask for an instance of MyWizard, the DI system looks for a provider in the MyWizardStep component's injector and doesn't find it, then looks up to MyWizardStep's parent (which is MyWizard) and asks that injector for an instance of the MyWizard class. Since each component registers itself in its own injector, MyWizard is available as an injectable class.

See [the Angular 2 advanced guide on dependency injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#find-parent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It somehow slipped my mind it's just a basic and common DI case...

Comment: np. I think that's one of the most amazing things about the design of Angular 2 in comparison to ng1 - in version 2, you don't have as many exceptions. There's a few basic rules and most use cases can be solved within the constraints of those rules.  NG1 wasn't designed as much as it was grown, and it's full of edge cases and exceptions. The worst part of migrating from ng1 to 2 is getting rid of that "thinking in exceptions"

Comment: BTW, just because you can get a hold of a parent instance through the DI system doesn't mean that it's generally a good idea for a child component to know too much about its parents.  (I know the question was just about concepts, but just throwing in the warning)

Comment: Not too much, but a child should at least know who their parent is ;-) Will have to read that chapter thoroughly and figure out the A > B > C case.